# I'm having problems with EXT.JS model association

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to create a form with a model(A) that has a association with another model(B);
When I select A to edit, the combo box with B doesn't appear.
Can anyone give me a light?

I used this association method:

```
hasOne: [{
    model: 'ModelB',
    name: 'modelb',
    associationKey: 'modelb'
}],
```

Here is the combo box to model B:

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    fieldLabel: 'Model B',
    name: 'modelb',
    bind: {
        selection: '{modelObject.modelb}'
    },
    store: {
        model: 'ModelB',
        autoLoad: true
    },
    reference: 'modelbCombo',
    forceSelection: true,
    queryMode: 'local',
    valueField: 'id',
    displayField: 'name',
    emptyText: 'Select a Model B...'
},
```

Comment: What versions of extjs are you using. If there is a possibility, share your examples in https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor

Comment: Thanks for reply. I found the problem, it's in the route of petname api.